# taxonomy_edit_form_fields output after term fields

Tags: taxonomy, hooks, actions, terms

I'm using the following code to create a custom metabox on a custom taxonomy page.

```
$term_filter_name_edit = $type . '_edit_form_fields';
add_action($term_filter_name_edit, 'box_term', 1000, 1 );
function box_term() {
  echo 'Test output';
}
```

However, this outputs `Test output` **before** the default term fields. I want it to output **after** the default term fields.

How can I achieve this?

--

Curiously, using `_add_form_fields` outputs after the fields on the add page, but using `_edit_form_fields` seems to output before.

Comment: Even more curiously, the documentation seems to suggest that it _should_ output after the form fields. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see quite what that might be. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_edit_form_fields/

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

It seems this action is fired *within a table* element.

Removing the `_fields` part seems to have done the trick as this refers to an action fired later in the page, after the table.

```
$term_filter_name_edit = $type . '_edit_form';
add_action($term_filter_name_edit, 'box_term', 1000, 1 );
function box_term() {
  echo 'Test output';
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/edit-tag-form.php

Comment: It seems there are significant differences between `_edit_form` (which fires before the submit button) and `_add_form` (which fires after the submit button).